# If the sum of the digits of $n$ are divisible by 9, then $n$ is divisible by 9; help understanding part of a proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $n<1000$. If the sum of the digits of $n$ is divisible by 9, then $n$ is divisible by 9.

I got up to here:

$$100a + 10b + c = n$$
$$a+b+c = 9k,\quad  k \in\mathbb{Z}$$

I didn't know what to do after this, so I consulted the solution

The next step is:

$$100a+10b+c = n = 9k +99a+9b = 9(k +11a+b)$$

I don't get how you can add $99a + 9b$ randomly, can someone please explain this for me?

Comment: The statement is true for any positive integer $n$, but from what you've written, are you assuming that $n$ is a three-digit number?

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not adding it "randomly", we add it to both sides of the equation
$$a+b+c=9k$$
to produce$$\begin{align*}
(a+b+c)+99a+9b&=(9k)+99a+9b\\\\
100a+10b+c&=9k+99a+9b\\\\
n&=9k+99a+9b\\\\
n&=9(k+11a+b)
\end{align*}$$
The statement is true for any positive integer $n$, not just $n<1000$. The best way to prove that is through [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: This does not explain why it is added though, please explain the need to add 99a + 9b what is the reason for this?

Comment: And how do you know adding 99a + 9b will make 9k equal n?

Comment: To get $n$ on one side of the equation, and a quantity we know will be divisible by 9 on the other.

Comment: Remember that you **defined** $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that
$$n=100a+10b+c$$

Comment: To be honest, I am still lost, but this seems like a better answer than the other good answer, so I gave you a checkmark

Comment: You don't have to do that if you don't want to; there's no rush to accept an answer. Now, do you agree that we started out in this problem letting $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the hundreds, tens, and ones digit of $n$ respectively, so that
$$n=100a+10b+c\quad ?$$
And do you also understand why
$$(a+b+c)+(99a+9b)=100a+10b+c\quad ?$$

Comment: No I don't understand the second step

Comment: Addition is commutative; in other words, for any $x$ and $y$, we can rearrange them when we're adding:
$$x+y=y+x$$
Using this fact multiple times to rearrange the terms,
$$a+b+c+99a+9b=a+99a+b+9b+c$$
Now use that $$a+99a=100a,\qquad b+9b=10b.$$

Comment: Oh now I finally get it! Thanks so much. Here have an Oreo cookie as a reward!

Comment: Haha thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why they are thinking about three digits.  I would say let $n=10a+b$, where $b \lt 10$ (intuitively, $b$ is the ones digit and $a$ is all the rest).  Then $n \pmod 9 \equiv 10a+b = (10-1)a +a +b \equiv a+b \pmod 9$ shows we can "strip off" all the lowest digits and add them up.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still do not understand the need to strip off all the lowest digits. Can you rephrase the answer please (as a comment)

Comment: @AndrewMurray:  An example is that the remainder on dividing $123$ by $9$ is the same as dividing $12+3=15$ by $9$ because the difference is $120-12=12(10-1)=108$ which is divisible by $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to see it: Take the number $N = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} d_k 10^k$ where the $d_k$ are the digits, modulo 9 you have:
$$
N = \sum_{0 \le k \le n} d_k 10^k
  \equiv \sum_{0 \le k \le n} d_k \pmod{9}
$$
since $10 \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$, and so $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod{9}$ for all $k$.